# Typesetting a text together with its commentaries

Tags: parallel-texts

I am critically editing a piece of Sanskrit metric text and its two commentaries in prose. What I would like to do is keep the verses together in the upper part of the page, and below the commentaries A and B as paragraphs, roughly as in the sample output below:

[image]

I would however like my input to be structured in the order verse 1, commA 1, commB 1, verse 2, commA 2, commB 2 (Missing in my sample, which does occur. Sometimes, the other extreme, I might have more than a page of commentary for a verse also.), verse 3, commA 3, commB 3, and so on, with LaTeX deciding what fits on one page, similar as with (paragraphed) footnotes, which I suppose one could theoretically hack to do the task, but as I need several registers of critical apparatus (`reledmac`, not dealt with here yet, eventually that will be the topic of another (few?) question(s?).) that would probably not be the right approach here.

Below the code for my sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
fasdfsfdsa asdfdsd fdsfasfsa \\
dalsfdkj fdjdsjdf sldkdff dsf | \\
dsakdjlasjdsal dsjkdsj skds ksks \\
asdjalskda dsds asdsds lekfds || 1 || \\
\smallbreak
fasdfsfdsa asdfdsd fdsfasfsa \\
dalsfdkj fdjdsjdf sldkdff dsf | \\
dsakdjlasjdsal dsjkdsj skds ksks \\
asdjalskda dsds asdsds lekfds || 2 || \\
\smallbreak
fasdfsfdsa asdfdsd fdsfasfsa \\
dalsfdkj fdjdsjdf sldkdff dsf | \\
dsakdjlasjdsal dsjkdsj skds ksks \\
asdjalskda dsds asdsds lekfds || 3 || \\
\end{verse}
\medbreak
Commentary A: adfdsfdsa adsfsdfa || 1 || afasdfasd afdsfjksdflasdfa weroijfdskfsdf ssdfdsr dlfkds ldkjsdfs fsdijen fsdfs ljfdsdf || 2 || ikjfsdfd jfkfdsfd idfjfdjdkd wljejfdjdkdk fdskds ejdsjdfds lkfdsj dfne || 3 ||
\medbreak
Commentary B: adsfd efdjfds efdsfds liefsfdf fdsjejds flkf df ejfdkdfsjdsf~||~1~|| djfdskfd s efdsfkds lfdkjdfjfds lrgdgf fdsfddfsj || 3 || 

\end{document}
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: Try `reledmac`.

Comment: Is the question something like the following: How to have three separate input streams that TeX breaks into pages, filling up each page in an optimal manner (because sometimes commenaryA will be far bigger than commentaryB, or vice versa, and sometimes there will be little commentary for several lines of poetry)? Not easily achieved, I think. (Though I'd love to see it! I have a similar project in mind, only even more complicated because the shape of the sets of text are not purely rectangular....)

Comment: @jon Yes, this sounds like what I was thinking of. Would you like to write a bit more about what you had in mind?

Comment: A picture is maybe easier: http://daten.digitale-sammlungen.de/bsb00049967/image_253 (the text surrounding the text in the middle is the commentary on [here] several titles in book 11 of Justinian's Codex  where each commentary passage is conceptually the same as a footnote). The main text block varies in size depending on how much commentary is required at that particular section of the text.  Not easy to implement such automation....